# how I can color comment in specific color in my mode in codemirror

Tags: javascript, css, codemirror

I want to color my comment that come between the **/* */** in specific color in codemirror ... I search and found sample to color the string between the **" "** and it work fine .

when I replace the **" "** by **/* */** in the code then the code not color my comment .

the work code is :

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("strings", function() {
  return {
    startState: function() {return {inString: false};},
    token: function(stream, state) {
      // If a string starts here
      if (!state.inString && stream.peek() == '"') {
        stream.next();            // Skip quote
        state.inString = true;    // Update state
      }

      if (state.inString) {
        if (stream.skipTo('"')) { // Quote found on this line
          stream.next();          // Skip quote
          state.inString = false; // Clear flag
        } else {
           stream.skipToEnd();    // Rest of line is string
        }
        return "string";          // Token style
      } else {
        stream.skipTo('"') || stream.skipToEnd();
        return null;              // Unstyled token
      }
    }
  };
});
```

my try :
Note I only replace the **"** by **/** and **"** by **/** 
but the code not work 
this is my try online [jsbin but not work](http://jsfiddle.net/TcqAf/710/)

so what my wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [documentation](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html),

> **peek() → string**
>
> Returns the next character in the stream without advancing it. Will return a null at the end of the line.

`stream.peek()` only returns 1 character, you want to match `"/*"`, which is 2 characters.

You want to use `stream.match()`

> **match(pattern: string, ?consume: boolean, ?caseFold: boolean) → boolean**
>   **match(pattern: regexp, ?consume: boolean) → array**
>
> Act like a multi-character eat—if consume is true or not given—or a look-ahead that doesn't update the stream position—if it is false. pattern can be either a string or a regular expression starting with ^. When it is a string, caseFold can be set to true to make the match case-insensitive. When successfully matching a regular expression, the returned value will be the array returned by match, in case you need to extract matched groups.

This will return `true` if the current stream position matches `"/*"` and will eat the 2 characters:

```
stream.match('/*', true)
```

Comment: I try it but what about the function "stream.skipTo("*/")" it not work ... see the update in the link : http://jsfiddle.net/TcqAf/711/    and note the "/" at the end not color @Bertrand Marron